# Loosing thousands of observations using RODBC

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

Comparing base SAS to RODBC in R for accessing ORACLE SQl databases.

I'm trying to access to an ORACLE SQL database. If I run this in SAS with this code:

```
LIBNAME LIBNAME ORACLE SCHEMA=SCHEMA PATH="*****";

PROC SQL ;
CREATE TABLE work.eval_view AS
 SELECT * 
    FROM LIBNAME.VW_EVALUATION 
  ORDER BY ***** ;
QUIT;
```

IF I run this code, I get 153777 observations, which is what I would expect.

Then I want to run this code in R. I'm using the RODBC library. This is the code I run:

```
connect <- odbcConnect(dsn='****', rows_at_time =1, believeNRows=FALSE)

evaluation <- sqlQuery(connect, "SELECT * FROM ****.vw_evaluation")
```

But I get 4239 observations. The actual observations that do come in are the same as the ones that come in from SAS, just the majority of observations are missing.

If I change the `rows_at_time` input I change the amount of observations I get. `100` at a time gets me 10219 observations, `110` at a time get's me less observations, only 10120 observations.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem? It seems that people in other threads have suggested changing rows_at_time, but that isn't working so well for me.

Comment: How wide is your table and do you have very large text fields? This can impact memory allocation coming in. Try selecting a few columns. Consider using `odbcQuery()` and `sqlGetResults()` over `sqlQuery()` (a wrapper for the two). Play with the args like *believeNRows* and *max=0*. Even try `sqlTable()` over the query call. See page 18 of [RODBC documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf).

Comment: The large text field was the culprit, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would troubleshoot it by testing with the `ROracle` package which runs with the `DBI` package to connect to the database. I don't have access to an Oracle database to test with, but trying a second package will let you know if the issue with with your database interface or something else.

Note that `ROracle` seems to be maintained by Oracle itself, and so is hopefully well supported. I've used `DBI` quite a bit to interface with MySQL (`RMySQL`) and SQLite (`RSQLite`) databases, and haven't had issues returning very large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Parfait was correct! The problem was a 'comment section' column that contained long strings. Once that column was not being imported I got all the rows I expected.